# Can't open html file in browser with c++

Tags: html, c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
void statistics(){
 //processing code
    LPCTSTR helpFile = "report.html";
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", helpFile, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

If I put those code lines in 'main' function it works, but here it writes an error: "Error: a value of type"const char*" cannot be used to intialize an entity of type "LPCTSTR".
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ShellExecuteA` (for usage of `char`s) with those parameters. That should work.